# Can sandcastle read XmlDoc from an external file instead of header comments?

Tags: .net, documentation, sandcastle

[Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) turns triple slash comments into documtation like so:

```
///<summary>A class called Bob</summmary>
public sealed class Bob {}
```

The schema for the documentation is very robust. However, the more robust and verbose your documentation is the more annoying some people find it to actually browse and edit the source code. A good compromise would be able to do something like

```
///<summary>A class called Bob</summmary>
///<include href="projectDocs.xml" xpath="/Company/Product/Bob" />
public sealed class Bob {}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There's an [include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx) comment tag. Our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) has support for it and I believe Sandcastle has it too.